What is this unrequested [migration/]?
My lapto running Ubuntu 24.04 and no other OS suddenly started running the fan very hard today. I ran ps -ax to see what was using the cpu so heavily and saw the following:

  1 ?        Ss     0:02 /sbin/init splash
  2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
  3 ?        S      0:00 [pool_workqueue_release]
  4 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/R-rcu_g]
  5 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/R-rcu_p]
  6 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/R-slub_]
  7 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/R-netns]
  9 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H-events_highpri]
 10 ?        I      0:01 [kworker/0:1-events]
 12 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/R-mm_pe]
 13 ?        I      0:00 [rcu_tasks_kthread]
 14 ?        I      0:00 [rcu_tasks_rude_kthread]
 15 ?        I      0:00 [rcu_tasks_trace_kthread]
 16 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
 17 ?        I      0:01 [rcu_preempt]
 18 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
 19 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/0]
 20 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/0]
 21 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/1]
 22 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/1]
 23 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
 24 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
 27 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/2]
 28 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/2]
 29 ?        S      0:00 [migration/2]
 30 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
 31 ?        I      0:00 [kworker/2:0-cgroup_destroy]
 33 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/3]
 34 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/3]
 35 ?        S      0:00 [migration/3]
 36 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
 38 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/3:0H-events_highpri]
 39 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/4]
 40 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/4]
 41 ?        S      0:00 [migration/4]
 42 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
 44 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/4:0H-events_highpri]
 45 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/5]
 46 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/5]
 47 ?        S      0:00 [migration/5]
 48 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
 49 ?        I      0:00 [kworker/5:0-events]
 51 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/6]
 52 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/6]
 53 ?        S      0:00 [migration/6]
 54 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
 56 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/6:0H-events_highpri]
 57 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/7]
 58 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/7]
 59 ?        S      0:00 [migration/7]
 60 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
 62 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/7:0H-events_highpri]
 63 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/8]
 64 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/8]
 65 ?        S      0:00 [migration/8]
 66 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/8]
 68 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/8:0H-events_highpri]
 69 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/9]
 70 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/9]
 71 ?        S      0:00 [migration/9]
 72 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/9]
 74 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/9:0H-events_highpri]
 75 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/10]
 76 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/10]
 77 ?        S      0:00 [migration/10]
 78 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/10]
 80 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/10:0H-events_highpri]
 81 ?        S      0:00 [cpuhp/11]
 82 ?        S      0:00 [idle_inject/11]
 83 ?        S      0:00 [migration/11]
 84 ?        S      0:06 [ksoftirqd/11]
 85 ?        I      0:03 [kworker/11:0-i915-unordered]
 86 ?        I<     0:00 [kworker/11:0H-events_highpri]


My question is what are the [migration/x], [idle_inject/x] etc. processes and what caused them to start?
